# Error when migrating to Oracle 11g "Please check that the correct JDBC driver..."

Tags: corda

I'm trying to change the Corda Node database from H2 to Oracle 11g. In node.info I add the following information:

```
jarDirs : ["ojdbc6.jar"]
dataSourceProperties : {
    dataSourceClassName : oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource
    dataSource.url : "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:db11g"
    dataSource.user : "sys as sysdba"
    dataSource.password : "98765"
}
database : {
    transactionIsolationLevel : READ_COMMITTED
    schema : sys
}
```

So, when I run the code in database manager tool:

```
java -jar corda-tools-database-manager-3.1.jar --base-directory ./ --execute-migration
```

I get this error:

> ```
> Failed to create datasource.
> Please check that the correct JDBC driver is installed in one of the following folders:
>      - D:\XXX\XXX\XXX\banka\drivers
>      - ojdbc6.jar
>
> Caused By java.nio.file.NotDirectoryException: ojdbc6.jar
> ```

I make sure that I have the ojdbc6.jar in "drivers" folder in this node. Any one can tell me how to fix this problem?

Comment: The D: unit is a net unit???

Comment: This is my folder path

Comment: Unrelated, but: why are you using the `sys` account? That should **only** be used for DBA work. **Never**, ever store your own tables (or other objects) in the SYS or SYSTEM schema.

Comment: The error message seems to indicate that the tool thinks that `"ojdbc6.jar"` is a _directory_ rather than a filename. Given the property's name `jarDirs` I would expect you need to specify a directory (that contains the driver jar) for that property, not a filename.

Comment: It's work! Thank you so much @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `a_horse_with_no_name` states, `jarDirs` in the node's configuration file should be a directory, not a filename (e.g. `/Library/Java/postgres`).